# Autofac, resolve operation ended

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, owin, autofac

I just started with Autofac and trying to wire up Asp.Net Identity and I am failing. I thought I had everything working but I got stuck and need a hand.

The UserManager is injected via the constructor.

```
private readonly ApplicationUserManager UserManager;
        private readonly ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager;
        public UserController(IDocumentSession documentSession, ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager) : base(documentSession) {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }
```

My UserController.cs is having issues the moment I reach this async call.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
```

> This resolve operation has already ended. When registering components
>   using lambdas, the IComponentContext 'c' parameter to the lambda
>   cannot be stored. Instead, either resolve IComponentContext again from
>   'c', or resolve a Func<> based factory to create subsequent components
>   from.

The issue is that I get a pretty clear message but I don't know how to continue with it; should I register my ApplicationUserManager in a different way?

I have setup my container like this. I hope someone can take a look.

```
public static void RegisterContainer(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Autofac container .. 
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register all MVC Controllers
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // Register all services that implement the Module interface
            builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().ToArray());

            // Register the DocumentStore instance
            builder.Register(context => new RavenDocumentStoreFactory()
                .FindOrCreate())
                .As<IDocumentStore>()
                .SingleInstance();

            // Multi tenancy part      
            var tenantIdStrategy = new TenantIdStrategy();
            var multitenantContainer = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdStrategy, builder.Build());
            var tenantIds = new[]
            {
                "subdomain1.tickets",
                "localhost"
            };

            foreach (var tenantId in tenantIds)
            {
                var databaseName = $"ticketTenant-{tenantId.Replace('.', '_')}";



                multitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant(tenantId, b =>
                {
                    // Init RavenDB 
                    b.Register(context => new RavenDocumentSessionFactory(databaseName))
                        .InstancePerTenant()
                        .AsSelf();

                    // Session per request
                    b.Register(context => context.Resolve<RavenDocumentSessionFactory>()
                        .FindOrCreate(context.Resolve<IDocumentStore>()))
                        .As<IDocumentSession>()
                        .InstancePerRequest()
                        .OnRelease(x =>
                        {
                            x.SaveChanges();
                            x.Dispose();
                        });

                    //  ASP.Net Identity Registrations
                    b.Register(context => new UserStore<User>(context.Resolve<IDocumentSession>))
                        .AsImplemented‌​Interfaces()
                        .Instanc‌​ePerRequest()
                        .OnRelease(x =>  
                        {  
                            x.Dispose();
                        });

                    b.Register<IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>>(c => 
                        new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>() { 
                            DataProtectionProvider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionPr‌​ovider("ApplicationName") 
                    }); 

                    b.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf().Inst‌​ancePerRequest();
                    b.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
                    b.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InstancePerRequest();
                    b.Register<IDataProtectionProvider>(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();


                });
            }

            // Register in Owin
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(multitenantContainer);
            app.UseAutofacMvc();

            // Dependency Resolver to Autofac
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(multitenantContainer));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own issue, but honestly ... I haven't got a clue how I fixed this. It was just trial and error. This is the new configuration; the old part is commented.

It doesnt even need the last Register in Owin part... even commented it appear to work just fine now.

```
//  ASP.Net Identity Registrations
                    /*
                    b.Register(context => new UserStore<User>(context.Resolve<IDocumentSession>))
                        .AsImplemented‌​Interfaces()
                        .Instanc‌​ePerRequest()
                        .OnRelease(x =>  
                        {  
                            x.Dispose();
                        });

                    b.Register<IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>>(c => 
                        new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>() { 
                            DataProtectionProvider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionPr‌​ovider("ApplicationName") 
                    }); 

                    b.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf().Inst‌​ancePerRequest();
                    b.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
                    b.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InstancePerRequest();
                    b.Register<IDataProtectionProvider>(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();
                    */

                    b.Register(c => new UserStore<User>(c.Resolve<IDocumentSession>())).As<IUserStore<User>>().InstancePerRequest()
                        .OnRelease(x =>  
                        {  
                            x.Dispose();
                        });
                    b.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().InstancePerRequest();
                    b.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>().InstancePerRequest();
                    b.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InstancePerRequest();
                    b.Register<IDataProtectionProvider>(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Can i make one suggestion. Swap `InstancePerRequest` to `InstancePerLifetimeScope` this will save you a bunch of headaches down the road when you start working with scopes outside of requests. [Documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-lifetime-scope)

Comment: @Nico, thank you, very good suggestion. I've just read up on the information about it and nevery expected registrations could expire for children.